# How to authenticate google-indexing with a service account on a Drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, google-api-php-client, google-indexing-api

I'm trying to use the google indexing API on a Drupal site. I keep getting a 403 permission denied error.

I've enabled the API, created a service account, verified the site ownership using a meta tag, set owner permission to the service account and have downloaded the google-api-php-client library to make things easier. I put the php file on the server. When I go to the page, I get a 403 error. Permission denied.

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

//Set up service account credentials
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='. DRUPAL_ROOT . '/myjsonfile.json');

$client = new Google_Client();

// service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
//-----USING DEFAULT CREDENTIALS SET BY JSON FILE INSTEAD-----
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

// Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

// Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
$content = "{
  \"url\": \"urlToUpdate\",
  \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED\"
}";

$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

Edit: I have also tried using the $client->setAuthConfig() method as shown on googles documentation shown here: [Google indexing api](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/prereqs#examples)

Here is alternate code following google api

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

// service_account_file.json is the private key that you created for your service account.
$client->setAuthConfig('myjsonfile.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');

// Get a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';

// Define contents here. The structure of the content is described in the next step.
$content = "{
  \"url\": \"urlToUpdate\",
  \"type\": \"URL_UPDATED\"
}";

$response = $httpClient->post($endpoint, [ 'body' => $content ]);
$status_code = $response->getStatusCode();
```

Comment: When I go to the page ... ?

Comment: @EricLavault The php page that the code is on. It just echos the $status_code for me to see. Unfortunately for me, it keeps returning 403 :(

Comment: Have you checked that `DRUPAL_ROOT . '/myjsonfile.json'` is actually readable by your script (file permissions) ?

Comment: @EricLavault When I check with functions file_exists() and is_readable(), I get back that the json file exists and is readable.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer to my problem a while back, so I'm going to post the answer here. To my ire, the reason it wasn't authenticating, was because I registered the http://url instead of the https://url in the google console. So it did not recognize me as an owner of the site. The code is fine, just quadruple check to make sure you register the service account correctly.